# C++: How to call a function (lets say funA()) from a header file inside my own function whose name is also funA()?

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, overloading, name-conflict

I want to call a function `reverse(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)` from `<algorithm>` header file inside my function, whose name is also `reverse(int)`.

code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Solution{
public:
    int reverse(int x){
        string num = to_string(x);
        reverse(num.begin(), num.end());
    }
};
```

I thought it would automatically call the appropriate function based on the parameters passed just like function overloading. But, it doesn't.

I tried:

```cpp
namespace algo{
    #include<algorithm>
}
```

But it is giving a lot of errors.

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;`.  Instead, use `std::reverse` to be explicit.  More reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Trying to stick an entire header into an arbitrary namespace won't also put the implementation of that header into the same arbitrary namespace.  You'll also need to change the source code of that header file (in this case, the Standard C++ Library source code), and recompile that library.  Alternatively, just don't go there.

Comment: @Eljay Could you explain why function overloading did not work here?

Comment: There is no function overloading here.  Solution has only one member function:  `int reverse(int)`, which expects one `int` parameter.  When the compiler tries to match up `reverse(num.begin(), num.end());` to `int reverse(int)` it doesn't match, so the compiler emits an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh, now you're experiencing the reason people on StackOverflow are [always yelling about not using `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2602718). The issue is that you're bringing the whole namespace into the global namespace, which'll lead to clashes like this.

If you delete that line, however, now all of your imported functions stay in the `std` namespace, so you could do:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

// BAD
// using namespace std;

class Solution{
public:
    int reverse(int x){
        std::string num = std::to_string(x);
        std::reverse(num.begin(), num.end());
        return std::stoi(num); // Don't forget to return!
    }
};
```